# Spark Streaming on EC2: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: scala, maven, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to run spark-submit on a jar file that I created. When I run it locally on my machine it works correctly but when deployed onto Amazon EC2 it returns the following error.

```
root@ip-172-31-47-217 bin]$ ./spark-submit --master local[2] --class main.java.Streamer ~/streaming-project-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.<clinit>(StreamingContext.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
    at main.java.Streamer$.main(Streamer.scala:24)
    at main.java.Streamer.main(Streamer.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1592)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
... 14 more
```

Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <groupId>astiefel</groupId>
    <artifactId>streaming-project</artifactId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Streamer Project</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
        <!-- Put the Scala version of the cluster -->
        <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalanlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>breeze_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera-repo-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>3.1.3</version>-->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>2.13</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
                    <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- "package" command plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>2.4.1</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: what version of spark you have on ec2?

Comment: I have exactly the same error

Comment: I have the same error on both 1.5.0 and 1.5.1 (with scala sbt)

Comment: in my case the error is caused by this line:   val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

Comment: after struggling with this for quite a while; I also posted a question here: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/2227/shutdown-hook-priority-javalangnosuchfieldexceptio.html

Comment: Yeah that's where I'm getting the error. Thanks for posting it elsewhere

Comment: What version of Java are you using on that machine? And did you download the Spark binary distribution?

Comment: I'm using java version "1.7.0_85" and it automatically got installed when I created the cluster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you launch `spark-ec2` the default hadoop version is 1.2.1. However, the recent Spark versions (at least 1.5.1) requires the `SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY` field in the hadoop.fs.FileSystem class that was introduced in Hadoop 2+.

One fix to get around this problem is to start up your spark cluster with Hadoop version 2+. See `spark-ec2 --help` for available options. Example: `--hadoop-major-version=yarn` will install version 2.4 of Hadoop.

Comment: Thanks a lot; that fixed it for me.