# Spark Maven Vaadin Jetty ( ExceptionInInitializerError)

Tags: maven, apache-spark, jetty, vaadin

I am suffering from this error. I searched every where and I could not find a solution till now.

I am trying to link spark with vaadin but I am getting an exception every time when I call spark with the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1429)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1383)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.addShutdownHook(DiskBlockManager.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.<init>(DiskBlockManager.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.REWEPredictor.LoadData(REWEPredictor.java:95)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.MyVaadinUI.setREWE(MyVaadinUI.java:240)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.MyVaadinUI.init(MyVaadinUI.java:152)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:610)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:223)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:73)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1371)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1592)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
    ... 43 more
Caused by:

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.addShutdownHook(DiskBlockManager.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.<init>(DiskBlockManager.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.REWEPredictor.LoadData(REWEPredictor.java:95)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.MyVaadinUI.setREWE(MyVaadinUI.java:240)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.MyVaadinUI.init(MyVaadinUI.java:152)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:610)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:223)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:73)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1371)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1592)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
    ... 43 more
Caused by:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1592)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.addShutdownHook(DiskBlockManager.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.<init>(DiskBlockManager.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.REWEPredictor.LoadData(REWEPredictor.java:95)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.MyVaadinUI.setREWE(MyVaadinUI.java:240)
    at REWEChallenge.Team5.MyVaadinUI.init(MyVaadinUI.java:152)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:610)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:223)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:73)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1371)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Powered by Jetty://
```

my pom file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <vaadin.version>7.1.6</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <vaadin-widgets-dir>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</vaadin-widgets-dir>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
       <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0-alpha8</version>
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--
      Needed when using the widgetset optimizer (custom ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory).

      For widgetset compilation, vaadin-client-compiler is automatically added on the
      compilation classpath by vaadin-maven-plugin so normally there is no need for an
      explicit dependency.
    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spark Dependencies -->

 <!-- Spark Streaming 

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>

  -->

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
        <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
                <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This 
                    way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                </webappDirectory>
                <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                </hostedWebapp>
                <noServer>true</noServer>
                <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                <style>OBF</style>
                <strict>true</strict>
                <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                        <!-- <modules> <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module> 
                            </modules> -->
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        vaadin-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [7.1.6,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The need for the `SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY` field in Spark was added Sep 13, 2014

https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/ee6f1aa

That version of Spark requires at least Scala 2.10.4 to operate.

**Update:**

Upgrade your Hadoop to version 2.0 or better.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33268091/775715

Comment: I have the following: 
    - scala-library-2.10.5.jar
    - scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar
    - scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar

is it right ?

Comment: Your exception message says otherwise (at least from a runtime point of view)

Comment: I changed it to 2.10.4 and I got the same error. 
Do you know what I have to do ? 
I updated my question with the pom file

Comment: Thanks .... solved :)  I removed  hadoop core 1.2.1 and added hadoop client 2.7.1